# How to unite Radiobuttons in one Radiogroup that spreaded on Activity

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I have got an activity with 2 radiobuttons on it, but first one is on top, and the second is near the middle. Between radiobuttons there are many other views.
How can I unite these 2 radiobuttons in one group? 
When I make `<RadioGroup ...</RadioGroup>` all content of the Activity gone somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of what you're trying to do, but I think that you can place your views between your radiobuttons like this:

```
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/RG"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/RB1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="text1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview"
                android:text="Place your many other views like this" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/RB2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="text2" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: I copy this into xml file. I do not actually see any TextView on the screen.. I did like that already before. All views were gone.

Comment: Sorry this was my mistake. I wrote previously parameter android:orientation="horizontal" in Radiogroup, and that is why I couldn't see any other views in activity.

Comment: Did this actually work? I was trying the same thing, having my app crash, [and was told that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23973613/android-radio-group-oncheckchangedlistener-crashing-app) you cannot have any children of a radiogroup that are not radiobuttons.

Answer (score 2):

One way to unit your radiobuttons is to deactivate your 2nd radiobutton when the fist is activated and do the same for the other radiobutton using `OnCheckedChangeListener`

Here is basically how to do that.

```
RadioButton1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            RadioButton2.setChecked(false);

        });
```

Comment: thank you, actually I wanted to now this. This is much more general case.