# Android radio group onCheckChangedListener crashing app

Tags: android, oncheckedchanged, android-radiogroup

Any idea why this would crash my app when I select a radio button?

I've imported `android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener`, and I've also tried

```
new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
```

which was the solution to a similar post.

The code is (logcat added):

```
RadioGroup ringtone_radio_group = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.ringtone_radio_group);

    ringtone_radio_group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "checked id = " + checkedId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

The layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="left">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/ringtone_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="Hello!"/>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/ringtone_radio_group"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/ringtone_button_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/ringtone1"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/play_button_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ringtone_button_1"
                android:text="Play" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/ringtone_button_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/ringtone2"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

            <Button android:id="@+id/play_button_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Play" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/ringtone_button_3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/ringtone3"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

            <Button android:id="@+id/play_button_3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Play" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

The logcat:

```
05-31 11:09:36.053: E/AndroidRuntime(26969): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onRadioButtonClicked(View) in the activity class com.example.ringtones.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.RadioButton with id 'ringtone_button_1'
05-31 11:09:36.053: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3031)
05-31 11:09:36.053: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
05-31 11:09:36.053: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:100)
05-31 11:09:36.053: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
05-31 11:09:36.053: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-31 11:09:36.053: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-31 11:09:36.053: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-31 11:09:36.053: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-31 11:09:36.053: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-31 11:09:36.053: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-31 11:09:36.053: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:812)
05-31 11:09:36.053: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:579)
05-31 11:09:36.053: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-31 11:09:36.053: E/AndroidRuntime(26969): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onRadioButtonClicked [class android.view.View]
05-31 11:09:36.053: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
05-31 11:09:36.053: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
05-31 11:09:36.053: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3024)
05-31 11:09:36.053: E/AndroidRuntime(26969):    ... 12 more
05-31 11:27:02.010: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(27793): <ConfigWindowMatch:2081>: Format RGBA_8888.
05-31 11:27:02.020: D/memalloc(27793): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x509ca000 size:6103040 offset:5488640 fd:55
05-31 11:27:02.160: D/memalloc(27793): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x511ba000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:58
05-31 11:27:05.053: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(27793): <ConfigWindowMatch:2081>: Format RGBA_8888.
05-31 11:27:05.053: D/memalloc(27793): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x51467000 size:3645440 offset:3031040 fd:61
05-31 11:27:05.143: D/memalloc(27793): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x51855000 size:4874240 offset:4259840 fd:70
05-31 11:27:05.163: D/memalloc(27793): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x51cfb000 size:6758400 offset:6717440 fd:73
05-31 11:27:05.183: D/memalloc(27793): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x509ca000 size:6103040 offset:5488640
05-31 11:27:05.183: D/memalloc(27793): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x511ba000 size:614400 offset:0
05-31 11:27:06.944: D/memalloc(27793): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x51cfb000 size:6758400 offset:6717440
05-31 11:27:07.705: D/memalloc(27793): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x508ca000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:52
05-31 11:27:08.005: W/dalvikvm(27793): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a641f8)
05-31 11:27:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27793): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-31 11:27:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27793): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onRadioButtonClicked(View) in the activity class com.example.ringtones.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.RadioButton with id 'ringtone_button_1'
05-31 11:27:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27793):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3031)
05-31 11:27:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27793):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
05-31 11:27:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27793):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:100)
05-31 11:27:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27793):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
05-31 11:27:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27793):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-31 11:27:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27793):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-31 11:27:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27793):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-31 11:27:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27793):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-31 11:27:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27793):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-31 11:27:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27793):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-31 11:27:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27793):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:812)
05-31 11:27:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27793):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:579)
05-31 11:27:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27793):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-31 11:27:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27793): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onRadioButtonClicked [class android.view.View]
05-31 11:27:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27793):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
05-31 11:27:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27793):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
05-31 11:27:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27793):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3024)
05-31 11:27:08.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27793):    ... 12 more
```

Comment: Can you specify what error occurred?

Comment: If you have a crash, post a stack trace from logcat.

Comment: You need to read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17511168/2649012

Comment: @nrofis, "Unfortunately, RingTones has stopped".

Comment: @Karakuri posted logcat.

Comment: @DerGolem, wow, that seems like it is probably it.  I had no idea I couldn't put other views in radiogroup. That is pretty inconvenient. I'll give that solution a try and see if I can get it working in enough time to get my homework in. Otherwise, I'll have to try a different layout idea.  Thanks.

Comment: Always leave yourself free to change your UI for a better or alternative solution. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `android:onClick="onRadioButtonClick"` from each of your RadioButtons in XML. You should be handling the selection of the RadioButtons inside the `OnCheckedChangeListener` you are setting on the RadioGroup.

If you need to do special processing when a particular RadioButton is selected, you can use a `switch` statement inside of the `onCheckedChanged` callback - the `checkedId` argument is the `android:id` value of the selected RadioButton (or -1 if the selection is cleared).

Answer (score 2):

the problem you have is because of the onclick in your XML file so just delete the onclick in your XML attributes and implement onCheckedChangeListener like this:

```
            priorRadioGroup=(RadioGroup)fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.priorityRadioGroup);
        priorRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                switch(checkedId) {
                    //your code comes here
                }
            }
        });
```

when you set onclick in Layout XML file it means you should have the method you called in activity class, and you don't.
hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the cause of the crash in these lines:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onRadioButtonClicked(View) in the activity class com.example.ringtones.MainActivity for onClick handler
```

and

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onRadioButtonClicked [class android.view.View]
```

The problem is that you don't have a method `onRadioButtonClicked` in your `MainActivity`. Just declare it and you'll be fine.